# Calling Specific Data in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm working in AngularJS and have some data set up so that when I call ng-repeat, it will fetch the data. I have a list of stores, embedded in each is a list of store contacts and their roles. I currently have them sorted A-Z, but I would like the store manager to be at the top of the list, but I am unsure of how to call this particular role by itself. I currently use `{{contact.role}}` to get all of the roles repeated, but what is the syntax for specifying a particular role?

My code is as follows:

```
        <div class="contacts" ng-repeat="contact in storeInfo.contacts | filter:RoleText | orderBy:RoleOrder">
          <span class="role">
            {{contact.role}}
          </span>
        </div>
```

Thanks

Comment: Please show us the `storeInfo` value + current result + expected result to help you with a good answer.

Comment: Sorry I don't quite understand what you mean - I am fairly new to Angular. I just want to be able to just see the Store Manager contact repeated {{contact.role="Store manager"}} but this syntax is not correct?

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat It is like the example at the bottom of this, but I want to repeat only those with the name 'John' and then call all the other names in a repeat after